# DateTimePicker subfield selection

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datetimepicker

So I've been tasked with making a custom data-bindable nullable DateTimePicker. I have it working great. Only issue is, the users don't want to use the arrow keys to navigate the control. They want to use the tab key. However, if you press the tab key when in the DateTimePicker it will leave to the next control. I've worked around this by utilizing the below code. Now the issue is, I can't leave the control, lol. I don't know how to check which subfield I'm currently on so I know if I'm on the far left or far right subfield to just leave the control instead of continuing to cycle through. Anyone have any tips? It would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (!this.ShowCheckBox || (this.ShowCheckBox && this.Checked))
        {
            if (keyData == Keys.Tab)
            {
                // **THIS IS WHERE I'M STUCK
                // if not on far right subfield do below
                SendKeys.Send("{RIGHT}");
                return true;
            }
            else if (keyData == (Keys.Shift | Keys.Tab))
            {
                // **THIS IS WHERE I'M STUCK
                // if not on far left subfield do below
                SendKeys.Send("{LEFT}");
                return true;
            }
        }

        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

Comment: I'm not following the "left" and "right".  When I create a new `DateTimePicker` and drop it on a form, I have a control that displays `Tuesday, June 11, 2013` where there are three editable/navigable sections:  `June` `11` `2013`.  And I can left/right arrow amongst them.  I think it would help to know more about your custom control.

Comment: Correct, I can navigate amongst them too using the left/right arrow keys. But the users want to use the tab key to go left/right as well. Which is why I'm overloading this method so that when you press tab it acts as a "right" arrow key and if you hit shift+tab it acts as a "left" arrow key. I do this by utilizing the SendKeys.Send() method built int to MS's API. If you create a new control and inherit DateTimePicker and then add this method exactly, you should see what I'm talking about. Let me know if I'm not making sense...

Comment: There's just no way to find out which "field" has the focus, DTP doesn't have a way to select it and therefore not a way to ask either.  Compare to, say, DataGridView, you don't use the Tab key either to move to another column.  The IP Address control is probably more infamous for this.  Maybe better colors can make it clear to the user that DTP is its own control.  Educating your user or spinning your own is the only real solution.

Comment: @HansPassant Ok, thanks for the information. I've informed the users to use the arrow keys, but they're used to the 'tab' key and were requesting that functionality. It's a shame this isn't possible. Maybe as a side project I'll investigate creating my own control not inheriting from DTP sometime.

Comment: Inheriting DTP is a dead alley.  It is an unmanaged Windows component.  DateTimePicker is just a .NET wrapper class for it.